# Who was house of Chloe?

Tags: exegesis, 1-corinthians

In 1 Corinthians 1:11 Paul says:

> 11 For it has been reported to me about you, my brothers, by members
>   of Chloe’s household, that there is rivalry among you.

Who is Chloe here?

I'm looking to expand my understanding from a historical/traditional perspective. So any extra Biblical source is acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking through [several Bible commentaries](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/1_corinthians/1-11.htm), it looks like not a lot known definitively about Chloe.

While some have speculated that Chloe refers to a place, most commentators are reasonably sure that the name refers to a person:

> Some take Chloe to be the name of a place; a city so called is said to have been in Cappadocia; but it seems rather to have been the name of a woman. Horace (b) several times makes mention of a woman of this name, and so does Martial (c). Pausanias (d) calls the goddess Ceres by it, the goddess of husbandry; the word signifying green grass of the field.
>
> —Gill's Exposition of the Entire Bible

There is disagreement as to whether she belonged to the church of Corinth or not:

> It is uncertain whether she belonged to the Corinthian or to the Ephesian church.
>
> —Vincent's Word Studies
>
> The person the apostle speaks of was one that very probably lived at Corinth, and was a member of the church there, and at the head of a family of great worth and credit…
>
> —Gill's Exposition of the Entire Bible

It seems likely that the "members of Chloe's household" who provided Paul with the report of the rivalry were slaves

> Her name [Chloe] was evidently well known to the Corinthians, and some slaves of her household, probably travelling between Ephesus and Corinth, on their owner’s business, had brought to St. Paul the account of the distracted state of the church in their city.
>
> —Ellicott's Commentary for English Readers

The slaves mentioned later in 1 Corinthians may have been those slaves:

> It has been conjectured that Stephanas, Fortunatus, and Achaicus, Corinthians who were now with St. Paul at Ephesus (1 Corinthians 16:16), may have been Chloe's slaves or freedmen.
>
> —Pulpit Commentary

In general though, we don't know much more about her as she is never mentioned beyond this passage.

Answer (score 1):

Paul tells of a lot of spiritual things that are lacking or present in you ( the church) through names.

Another  example-

1 Corinthians 16:
17:
I am glad of the coming of Stephanas and Fortunatus and Achaicus: for that which was lacking on your part they have supplied.
18 For they have refreshed my spirit and yours: therefore acknowledge ye them that are such.

When you look up the name meanings you find it has meaning and can be read as talking directly to anyone in the church.

I see that Chloe means green grass and the beginning shoots of it. Likely he's talking about the fruit that Christ like behavior brings forth.